# isUserInRole source code or HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Where can I find the source code for isUserInRole? All I find are only interfaces or calling to super.isUserInRole

Comment: Note: J2EE is replaced by Java EE over 4 years ago. Based on your question history you're using Tomcat 6 (Servlet 2.5, part of Java EE 5.0) and even JSF 2.0 (part of Java EE 6.0 and backwards compatible up to Java EE 5.0 only), so I don't expect that you're actually using J2EE and I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in the **concrete** implementation. As you see, Java EE is an **abstract** API, it exist of almost only interfaces. It has the benefit that you can deploy your webapplication on whatever server you want.

The concrete implementations are called application servers and/or  servlet containers, like Sun Glassfish, IBM WebSphere, Oracle Weblogic, Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, etcetera. You need to check if your server implementation is open source and then download the source from the vendor's homepage.

Tomcat 6.0 for example is open source, you can download it [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) (check the *Source Code Distributions* links at the bottom). It is in the `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` class.